# Write text on background image is not responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to write some text on image, i set the image as background to my div element but when i write the text it goes outside the image in small screen devices. how can that be fixed to make it full responsive ? I've write this code :

```css
#background {
  background: url("../../imgs/88246.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="h-100 container-fluid">
  <div id="background" class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">AYMAN TARIG</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use two images, one on top of the other, background image struggles with responsive requirements.

Comment: If the text isn't part of the image you can control it with CSS, media query or using vw measures.

Comment: @pokeybit how to use two images ?

Comment: Change your background-size to `background-size: cover;` and then you can change your `background-position` if you like

Comment: @AymanTarig use css `position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;` on the image you wish to be on top and place it after the image you want underneath. Don't forget to assign `position:relative;` to the parent container if it's not set by default. You might need to use css `z-index` also which controls which dom element appears behind or in front. Google is your friend :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by playing around with vw as the font-size and image width so they both resize together responsively. Read more about [vw here](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/).

Here's an example of how you can make it work:

```
#background {
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547845737-153b5373560f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2531&q=80") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 20%;
  width: 25vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 6vw;
}
```

If you go this go codepen you can see what I'm talking about in action:

https://codepen.io/MatthewRader/pen/aMrvrx

Answer (score 0):

TABLET

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
 h1 { font-size:SIZETHATFITS}}
```

PHONE

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 480px){
 h1 { font-size:SIZETHATFITS}}
```

@media screen and (max-width: #px) will only affect the font-size up to that max-width.